# 403 Forbidden in Local after modification of apache2.conf

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I modified the file `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` for a WordPress permalink problems, but now I can't access on my `localhost`.

I changed

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        Require all granted
```

After `a2enwrite` and reload apache2 my server doesn't work.

I work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Can you help me?

Comment: Thanks  @tinlyx , my post is professional now.

Comment: Resolved ! `Require all granted` it's a good way with the correct client permissions.